# Ktor: Bearer token injected by Dagger Hilt fails at first

Tags: dagger-hilt, ktor, ktor-client

Calls made by Ktor fails first most of the time and then use the `refreshTokens` to get a token and re-try the calls..

This is not acceptable as I see a LOT of Unauthenticated calls, therefore most calls I get is made 2x,  this effectively almost double my network call count.

The ONLY time the calls is authenticated properly is when the previous call was made to the same end point.

#### Question:

How can I improve this situation so that the token is provided ONCE to all Ktor end-points and
until the token is replaced (via valid login)

I use `androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences` to store my token and `settingsRepository.getAuthToken()` correctly retreive it

#### My DI

I use Dagger Hilt to inject my Bearer token this way

```kotlin
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideBearerAuthProvider(
        settingsRepository: SettingsRepository
    ) = BearerAuthProvider(
        realm = null,
        loadTokens = {
            val token = settingsRepository.getAuthToken()
            if (token == null) {
                BearerTokens(accessToken = "fake", refreshToken = "")
            } else {
                BearerTokens(accessToken = token, refreshToken = "")
            }
        },
        refreshTokens = {
            val token = settingsRepository.requireAuthToken()
            token?.let { BearerTokens(accessToken = it, refreshToken = "") }
        },
        sendWithoutRequestCallback = { httpRequestBuilder ->
            httpRequestBuilder.url.host == USER_LOGIN
        }
    ).also { bearerAuthProvider ->
        settingsRepository.addOnClearListener(bearerAuthProvider::clearToken)
    }
    
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiClient(
        bearerAuthProvider: BearerAuthProvider,
    ) = HttpClient(Android) {
        install(Logging) {
            logger = Logger.ANDROID
            LogLevel.ALL
        }
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            gson()
        }
        install(Auth) {
            providers += bearerAuthProvider
        }
    }
```

#### My ApiService

This is where the HttpClient is injected

```kotlin
abstract class BaseApiService(
    protected val httpClient: HttpClient,
    protected val baseUrl: String,
) {
    protected suspend inline fun <reified T> get(endpoint: String, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = {}): T {
        return httpClient.get(urlString = baseUrl + endpoint, block = block).body()
    }
    
    protected suspend inline fun <reified T> post(endpoint: String, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit): T {
        return httpClient.post(urlString = baseUrl + endpoint, block = block).body()
    }
    
    protected suspend inline fun <reified T> put(endpoint: String, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = {}): T {
        return httpClient.put(urlString = baseUrl + endpoint, block = block).body()
    }
    
    protected suspend inline fun <reified T> patch(endpoint: String, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit): T {
        return httpClient.patch(urlString = baseUrl + endpoint, block = block).body()
    }
    
    protected suspend inline fun <reified T> delete(endpoint: String, block: HttpRequestBuilder.() -> Unit = {}): T {
        return httpClient.delete(urlString = baseUrl + endpoint, block = block).body()
    }
}
```

#### UserApiService

```kotlin
class UserApiService @Inject constructor(
    httpClient: HttpClient
) : BaseApiService(httpClient, BASE_URL) {
    
    suspend fun authenticate(): BasicApiResponse<Unit> =
        get(endpoint = USER_AUTHENTICATE)
    
    suspend fun login(loginRequest: LoginRequest): BasicApiResponse<AuthApiResponse> =
        post(endpoint = USER_LOGIN) {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            setBody(loginRequest)
        }
    
    suspend fun updateUserProfile(updateProfileRequest: UpdateProfileRequest): BasicApiResponse<UserApiResponse> =
        patch(endpoint = USER) {
            contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
            setBody(updateProfileRequest)
        }
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I use data classes passing variables to the json payloads e.g.

```kotlin
data class LoginRequest(
    val email: String? = null,
    val password: String
)
```

2. In above code I also included the `sendWithoutRequestCallback` endpoint

```kotlin
sendWithoutRequestCallback = { httpRequestBuilder ->
    httpRequestBuilder.url.host == USER_LOGIN
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the `sendWithoutRequestCallback` work for you?

Comment: Will check and report

Comment: `sendWithoutRequestCallback` is NOT the issue here, as you can see in my code I use it to make sure my login endpoint DOES NOT get the Bearer token, which is the only part of `BearerAuthProvider` that actually work reliably

- problem still exist!

Comment: I am sorry to say @Aleksei, but the calls made by Ktor is NOT stable, Sometime I need to re-try them 5-6x then they go through!, the bug seem to be in the `BearerAuthProvider` stability!  I made tests and the DI inject the correct values from DataStore for the token but somehow Ktor is NOT  using it!  The server side just report `401 Unauthorized` until with luck it passes the token correctly! `2022-12-18 11:41:26.534 [DefaultDispatcher-worker-9] TRACE Application - 401 Unauthorized: PATCH - /user`

Comment: Could you please share the code where `BaseApiService` is used?

Comment: I amended my question to include it more readable!